# How to capture division and ignore when preceded by semicolon

Tags: python, regex

```
pattern = r'(\S+)\s*(![;])/\s*(\S+)'
regex = re.compile(pattern,re.DOTALL)
for result in regex.findall(data):
    f.write("Division" + str(result)+ "\n\n\n")
```

I am using following expression to capture when division is occurring but want to ignore when division symbol is preceded by ";" . This regex is not working

How can i make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Use [negative look-behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
pattern = r'(\S+)\s*(?<!;)/\s*(\S+)'
```

- `(?<!;)/` will match `/` only if `/` is not preceded by `;`

---

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\S+)\s*(?<!;)/\s*(\S+)', '1/2  and 1;/4  12 / 6')
[('1', '2'), ('12', '6')]
```